# Merge unregistered user account

Tags: support, status-completed

I read that it is "strongly encouraged" to merge unregistered accounts to registered ones. It seems a little bit odd to me to request this through posting a regular question, but if this really is the way to go, please merge https://serverfault.com/users/144483/karma-fusebox into this account. :)

Even though this account is quite young, I plan on spending some time here and would like to keep easier track of that one question I posted while being unregistered.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Merged

Comment: That was fast, thank you very much.

Comment: ♫ I get the urge to merge...♪ I get the urge to merge with youuuu ♫

Comment: @WesleyDavid . . . creepy cat.