# Merge unregistered user account with registered account

Tags: support

Based on this question: [Merge unregistered user account](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3858/merge-unregistered-user-account)

I am requesting that https://serverfault.com/users/212260/canon2k14 be merged into this account :)

It would greatly be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To merge accounts you have to request it here: https://serverfault.com/contact

Moderators can no longer merge accounts because some of the minor SE sites have/had careless moderators who can't be trusted with this responsibility.

Comment: Your response is much appreciated. Since both accounts are on serverfault.com, I had to use [http://serverfault.com/contact](http://serverfault.com/contact).